# Unity Dash Graphical Glitches in Ubuntu 13.04 with ATI Graphics

Tags: unity, ati, graphics

I have a very noticeable transparent glitch in the Unity Dash. It does no transparency at all and instead shows a green to red color transition with black checkered boxes. This is an entirely different visual glitch than the one that affects Intel Graphics Cards. This glitch only happens when I open the dash or the Shutdown dialogs. When the dash is not open, The unity left bar displays as it should with no glitch.

[image: Green to Red checkered board effect.]

The computer that has this glitch is a 2008 Toshiba Satellite L355D-S7825 Laptop. The graphics card is a ATI Radeon X1250. This computer also has had very bad graphics performance on Unity ever since Ubuntu 11.10, showing very choppy transitions and animations. I dual boot it with Windows Vista.

Comment: Please post a comment telling what version of fglrx (the ATI binary X.Org driver) that you are using on your laptop.

Comment: I'm using the stock X.org driver that ships with 13.04. This is a clean install. The fglrx driver is no longer compatible with this graphic card anymore. Never installed fglrx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but I got it fixed by disabling Unity Panel transparency from "Panel" tab and Background Blur from "Search" tab with Unity Tweak Tool.

Answer (score -1):

I have a Toshiba Satellite A210-MS5, with a X1200 ATI Radeon, and solved the same problem just by disabling "Background Blur" in the "Search" tab with Unity Tweak Tool.
-releve1403